# What is watershed in the context of image processing?

Tags: image-manipulation, computer-vision

I am new to image processing using Python.  Now I am learning OpenCV and the mahotas module in Python.  Many functions in these modules are related to watershed of an image.  I don't know what watershed means for an image.  Here is an example from the OpenCV documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/search.html?q=watershed&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watershed transformation is an image enhancement method. You can think of it like a possible preprocessing step to improve the results of your algorithm.

This site has some imho very illustrative animation: http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~beucher/wtshed.html

Wikipedia has an explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)